# Customise border drawing for bars in lattice barchart

Tags: r, panel, bar-chart, data-visualization, lattice

In my desparate attempts to publish a paper, I'm trying to make a fancy infographic from a simple data in the fruitless hope to lure a reviewers with an attractive images. As one option I'm making bar charts with an extended line in the bottom of each bar, similar to those created by [Nicholas Felton in this example](http://feltron.com/FAR12_05.html).

So its going well, overall, mostly. But I'm using a very cheap trick to create those 'extended borders' in the bottom of each bar - I add `panel.abline(...)` in the arbitrary location that roughly overlaps with the bottom of each bar. Let me illustrate:

```
data <- t(data.frame(urban = 10, suburban = 6, rural = 4))#exmaple data 
barchart(d, col="orange", xlim=c(0,15),
         scales=list(y=list(alternating=0)),#get rid of y-axis labels,
         border = "transparent",#make bars borders transprent
         par.settings = list(axis.line = list(col = "transparent")),
         panel = function(x,y,...) {
           panel.barchart(x,y,...)
           panel.abline(h=seq(0.66, 3.66,1), col="orange", lwd=0.7)#pathetic hack
           panel.axis(side=c("left"), at=1:3, half=F, ticks = F, 
                      outside=F, labels=rownames(d))

         })
```

which results in this bar chart

[image]

Now, its ok, but I want to make quite a few of those barcharts, so I'll most likely have to make a small tweaks in each of those `panel.abline` depending on size, number of variables, etc. Plus, its not a perfect overlay. So I'm wondering whether there is some neat option to hack the `border` argument (which is `transparent` at the moment), or any other argument, to create those 'extended lines' in the bottom of bars like a pro. Only lattice suggestions please.

It would be a bonus if you also know how to get rid of this grey line running vertically at the x=0.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to create a custom panel function that takes into account the `box.width` of your bars. After some experimentation I came up with this, which seems to work:

```
panel = function(x, y, ...) {
  dots <- list(...)
  br <- dots$box.ratio
  panel.barchart(x, y, ...)
  panel.abline(h = seq_along(x) - 0.5*(br/(br+1)), col="orange", lwd=0.7)
}
```

Try it:

```
d <- t(data.frame(urban = 10, suburban = 6, rural = 4, other=5))

barchart(d, col="orange", xlim=c(0, 15), box.ratio=5,
         scales=list(y=list(alternating=0)), 
         border = "transparent", 
         par.settings = list(axis.line = list(col = "transparent")), 
         panel = function(x, y, ...) {
           dots <- list(...)
           br <- dots$box.ratio
           panel.barchart(x, y, ...)
           panel.abline(h = seq_along(x) - 0.5*(br/(br+1)), col="orange", lwd=0.7)
         }
)
```

[image]

---

It also works for more data points and a different `box.ratio`:

```
d <- t(data.frame(urban = 10, suburban = 6, rural = 4, other=5, rubbish=7))

barchart(d, col="orange", xlim=c(0, 15), box.ratio=9,
         scales=list(y=list(alternating=0)), 
         border = "transparent", 
         par.settings = list(axis.line = list(col = "transparent")), 
         panel = function(x, y, ...) {
           dots <- list(...)
           br <- dots$box.ratio
           panel.barchart(x, y, ...)
           panel.abline(h = seq_along(x) - 0.5*(br/(br+1)), col="orange", lwd=0.7)
         }
)
```

[image]

Comment: Thats it, exactly what I need, thanks @Andrie ! PS: Any idea how to get rid of this grey vertical line at the left side of bar plot?

Comment: @GeekOnAcid I know nothing about working with lattice!

Comment: Just figured it out - need to add `reference.line = list(col = "transparent")` to the list of `par.settings`.